# What is the use of "wouldn't"?

Tags: modal-verbs, modality

What is the use of "wouldn't" in this sentence?

"I was trying to get to sleep, but Jimmy wouldn't stop talking"

Thanking you
Scottish

Answer (score 1):

*Would* is the **past tense of will**. In other words, he wasn't going to stop.

Also, the past tense form can express the **subjunctive mood**, as in "would you?", so "he wouldn't" is just the negation. But this is a [slightly more complicated interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Would), not to say ambiguous.